# Complex manifold $X$ with $\dim H^0(X,\Omega^{\dim_{\mathbb{C}} X})>2$

Tags: complex-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Are there any complex surface or threefold $X$ with
$$
\dim H^0(X,\Omega^{\dim_{\mathbb{C}} X})>2?
$$
I am asking this because I don't know any example while there are complex curves of genus greater than one. I guess that there are no such example. If so, could someone kindly explain why? Any counter example is also welcome.

**Edit**
My question turns out to be a silly question. Please ignore this.

Comment: Take $X=C_1×C_2$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are smooth curves. Then $h^0(X,K_X)=g(C_1)g(C_2)$ which can be as big as you wish

Comment: You are right. I think they belong to surfaces of general types and hence I am not familiar with and haven't seen them. 

Comment: Indeed they are surfaces of general type. You can start to study them  in Beauville's book or in Barth-Peters-Van de Ven 

Comment: Any abelian threefold also satisfies this.

Comment: They are not necessarily surfaces of general type! 

Comment: Ok, ok. But as soon as $g(C_1)$ and $g(C_2)$ are at least $2$ they are :-)
 